# Pandas : Removing duplicates row based on some conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataset in excel which looks as below.

```
name,role,org
abc,admin,123
abc,agent,123
abc,end-user,123
abc,admin,124
abc,admin,123
bcd,admin,125
abc,admin,126
abc,agent,127
abc,agent,123
abc,end-user,130
abc,end-user,130
abc,agent,123
bc,agent,123
bc,admin,123
vcf,end-user,123
```

I am trying to filter some user based on certain conditions.

Admin and agents can't have multiple name in one org.

An org can have many end-users with same name (so want to keep end-user as it is )

I tried so many things since yesterday but  no luck . Here is what I am trying

```
df.loc[(df['role'] == 'agent' ) | (df['role'] == 'admin' ) | (~df['org'] )]
```

But above code is exactly returning the row as input.

Please help me out with this

Expected  Ouput

```
name,role,org
abc,admin,123
abc,agent,123
abc,end-user,123
abc,admin,124
bcd,admin,125
abc,admin,126
abc,agent,127
abc,end-user,130
abc,end-user,130
bc,agent,123
bc,admin,123
vcf,end-user,123
```

Comment: Is possible post data in text?

Comment: "Admins and agents can't have a same name in an org" but in your expected output admin and agent both have the same name 'abc' within the org 123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for remove duplicates `agent, admin` per 3 columns:

```
df1 = df[~(df['role'].isin(['agent','admin']) & df[['org', 'role', 'name']].duplicated())]
```

If only 3 columns:

```
df1 = df[~(df['role'].isin(['agent','admin']) & df.duplicated())]
```

---

```
print (df1)
   name      role  org
0   abc     admin  123
1   abc     agent  123
2   abc  end-user  123
3   abc     admin  124
5   bcd     admin  125
6   abc     admin  126
7   abc     agent  127
9   abc  end-user  130
10  abc  end-user  130
12   bc     agent  123
13   bc     admin  123
14  vcf  end-user  123
```

Comment: could you please look into questions once again  I did some changes

Comment: @burning - Can you add expected output?

Comment: @could you please review now. updated expected output.